# How to use Switch-statement inside a Stream

Tags: java, foreach, switch-statement, java-stream, bigdecimal

I need to get a balance sum from a list of type `List<TransactionSumView>`, which I'm receiving from the database.

My `TransactionSumView` interface:

```java
//projection interface
public interface TransactionSumView {
        
    String getType();
    BigDecimal getAmount();
}
```

Please see my implementation below:

```java
List<TransactionSumView> listSum = transactionsRepository.findAllSumByAcc1IdGroupByType(id);
        
BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

// forEach loop
for (TransactionSumView list : listSum) {
    switch (list.getType()) {
        case "E":
        case "T":
            sum = sum.subtract(list.getAmount());
            break;
        case "I":
            sum = sum.add(list.getAmount());
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I solve it using Stream API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `map()` and [`reduce(identity,accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) operations.

[`BigDecimale.negate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#negate()) can be applied to change the sign of a value to represent the cases when it should be subtracted.

```
List<TransactionSumView> listSum = transactionsRepository.findAllSumByAcc1IdGroupByType(id);
    
BigDecimal sum = listSum.stream()
    .map(sumView -> "I".equals(sumView.getType()) ?
        sumView.getAmount() : sumView.getAmount().negate()
    )
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```